# What are the naming conventions for common controls while working within Visual Studio in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble finding a site that goes into detail about naming conventions for the common controls of Visual Studio. Either a website or list would be appreciated.

I'm not looking for naming conventions for namespaces, classes, methods, or variables.
I am looking for naming conventions for things like buttons and labels.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is the naming convention behind "label" and "textbox"?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578254/naming-conventions-for-controls

Comment: Are you asking about using "btnOK" vs. "buttonOK"?

Comment: I'm asking about anything other than the default given by Visual Studio. So btnOK and buttonOK are both answers to my question.

Comment: Yes, I am now aware that my question is a duplicate, I guess my punctuation and use of detail caused that other question not to show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Best practices for C# GUI naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246546/best-practices-for-c-gui-naming-conventions)

It seems that this is still something of a theological war with no accepted convention in the wider community.

Comment: My pleasure; actually we were discussing this at work today as we have just been reviewing our coding standard. As a group we opted for controlNameDescribingNoun, i.e. comboBoxCustomerNames. One guy was all in favour of uxDescribingNoun, i.e. uxDescribingNoun; he said he had used that at a previous company and it seemed to work well. I personally feel like adding the type is quite helpful, but yes it is cumbersome.

Comment: our convention is name it for what it does, so a save button is called "save" an add user button called "addUser", makes it nice and easy, you end up with save.Click += ... The only excepion is where you need to program against a label, which would otherwise match the name of an inter-active control, so it might gate the name "addUserLabel". Hungarian notion is not my favourite clutter to see in code

Answer (score 1):

I typically use a rather simple convention:

```
_buttonSubmit (ASP:Button Called Submit)
_dropDownYear (ASP:DropDownList for Years)
_placeHolderSomething (ASP:PlaceHolder for something)
```

Now, winForms, WPF, or ASP.NET, I think it's a good idea to always prefix your name with the control type, so when using it in a code behind, you instantly know what it is.

```
_radioButtonOne
```

Without mousing over for intellisense, you can be sure it's a Radio Button, etc. In addition, the '_' in front usually separates it from local variables as an instance specific member.

```
_radioButtonOne.Checked = true;
someLocalVariable++;
```

Comment: Thanks, but why the underscores?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if there is an actuall standard, as lots of developers like to argue pro's and cons on humpback and other notations.

I just finished up my program at fanshawe, and throughout the years they have recommended using hungarian notation.

That being said, here is some exmaples of how we were taught;

```
lblName - label
txtName - text box
cmbName - combo box
drpName = drop down
```

Really, you want to associaite the variable name with what the variable actually is.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation